# What version of .NET runtime is needed for a software written in .NET 4.5?

Tags: .net, windows, .net-4.5

This is a simple question. I have been writing a software with .NET 4.5 (which is now Beta). What version of .NET runtime is needed to run this software? Is it 4.5? Some older?

Also, are .NET updates part of Windows Update?

Comment: Agree with the answers below. However, if you aren't using .NET 4.5 specific functionality, you can re-target the application to 2.0 and above depending on the features you require.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to run 4.5 compiled assemblies you **must** have the 4.5 framework installed.  The 4.5 install is an in place upgrade which is mostly forwards compatible with 4.0 but is definitely not backwards compatible.

One particular place that can trip you up is type forwarders.  The 4.5 framework contains a huge number of new type forwarders (over 1,100 of them).  A type forwarder is a way for an assembly to declare that a type moved from assembly A to assembly B.  The CLR will silently redirect any references to the given type from A to B.

An assembly compiled against 4.5 though will emit a reference to the type as if it existed in assembly B.  If you then run that assembly against a 4.0 install it will expect the type to be in assembly B and it won't be.  The result will be a type load exception.

Concrete Example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var attrib = new ExtensionAttribute();
    Console.WriteLine(attrib);
}
```

Compile that code on a 4.5 box and then try to run it on a 4.0 box.  The result will be a type load exception.  The `ExtensionAttribute` type moved from System.Core in 4.0 to mscorlib in 4.5

Comment: Note: Vista or later required (not supported on XP)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a more important question is "What OS do I require for .NET 4.5?"

Here's the installation page first of all

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek

The biggest gotcha is you can't run 4.5 on Windows XP - it's just too old (>10 years)

So don't assume you can if this is going to be an issue in your environment!

[4.5 requires](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww) one of the following:

- Windows 8 (32-bit and 64-bit editions)
- Windows 7 (32-bit and 64-bit editions)
- Windows Vista SP2 (32-bit and 64-bit editions)
- Windows Server 2012 (64-bit edition)
- Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-bit edition)
- Windows Server 2008 SP2 (32-bit and 64-bit editions)

Answer (score 1):

The .Net 4.0 runtime. 4.5 is more .Net library goodness. The CLR version is not changing.

If you coding in C# the compiler is changing, but it's compiles CLR 4.0 IL.

http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/04/net-4-5-multitargeting

Comment: The CLR version is in fact changing.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on whether you're writing a Metro-style app.  For Metro-style apps (Windows 8), you're actually using a subset of the .NET 4.5 framework with a special Metro-only runtime.  For all other apps, .NET 4.5 uses the .NET 4.0 runtime with additional libraries (similarly to .NET 3.0 and .NET 3.5 being able to run on the .NET 2.0 runtime).

Comment: And yes, .NET updates are part of Windows Update, including both framework/runtime updates and security updates.  (You can get them separately from Microsoft's download center, as well.)

Answer (score 1):

The CLR versions are 1.0, 1.1, 2.0, and 4.0. The other versions of the .NET Framework simply provide additional types. .NET 3 and 3.5 run on CLR 2.0. .NET 4.5 runs on CLR 4.

Note: You still need .NET 4.5 to run 4.5 apps.

Comment: This is not strictly true. The 4.5 version, in addition to providing new types, also moved existing types between assemblies. If you reference those types (which exist in 4.0 and 4.5), build on 4.5 and deploy to 4.0 you will receive a runtime exception.